# How to get from the distribution function to the energy equation in thermodynamics?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

**In a college class, the professor asked me to investigate a certain problem and try to solve it but I have been trying for hours without success. Here is the description he gave me, I hope someone can help me:**

Maxwell and Boltzmann used statistical mechanics to analyze the properties of the ideal gas. They showed that the number of gas particles of mass $m$ with a velocity within the interval $v + dv$ is proportional to $e^{\left(-\frac{mv^2}{2kT}\right)}(4\pi v^2)\;dv$.

Using this distribution function we can calculate the average value of $mv^2$:

$$\frac{\int_0^\infty mv^2e^{\left(-\frac{mv^2}{2kT}\right)}(4\pi v^2)\;dv}{\int_0^\infty e^{\left(-\frac{mv^2}{2kT}\right)}(4\pi v^2)\;dv}$$

Prove that the above expression leads us to the well-known equation of thermodynamics:

$$\vec{E_c}=\frac{3}{2}kT$$

As a suggestion, it is recommended to use $x=\frac{mv^2}{2kT}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: utilize the formula from [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral):
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a x^2} \ dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} $$
and Feynman's trick (differentiation of the parameter $a$)
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-a x^2} \ dx = - \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} $$

Comment: I had never been taught the two integrals you mentioned. Thank you very much, after reading for a while the article you linked along with others that I found on the way and quite useful, I was able to find the result.